# How is this resetting the alarm?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I am have been reading over this tutorial for creating repeating apps:

http://rdyonline.net/android-bytes-alarms/

I have followed the instructions and it is working beautifully. However I don't like using something if I don't understand how it works.

Alarm manager is using an version >= 19 so instead of alarm repeating (exact) it requires a one off alarm that is reset on exiting the intent.

Now as I said it is working, Every 15 minutes it is going off (in my version). I can see that they are bundling data with the intent, but I really have no understanding what is re-triggering the single shot alarm.

This is their code:

> Repeating alarms
>
> If you’re targeting any Android version before API 19 (KitKat), or,
>   you don’t need them to be exact then repeating alarms are nice and
>   easy. All you need in this case is to use the setRepeating call.
>
> In some cases, it will be important that you set a repeating alarm
>   that is accurate, I’ll go in to a little more detail on how to handle
>   this.
>
> The trick here is to make sure you schedule the next alarm once the
>   previous alarm goes off. You’ll have to check whether the alarm you
>   have set is intended to be repeated and also make sure the platform
>   you’re running on is above API 19

```
@Override
public void onReceive(android.content.Context context,
        android.content.Intent intent) {

    WrappedAlarmManager am = new WrappedAlarmManager(context);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (am.isSingleAlarm(extras)) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Single alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (am.isRepeatAlarm(extras)) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Repeat alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            am.scheduleRepeatingAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

> A quick check to see if it’s a repeating alarm and then the repeating
>   alarm is scheduled again. Below are the two pertinent methods to deal
>   with this logic:

```
public boolean isRepeatAlarm(Bundle extras) {
    return extras.containsKey(KEY_REPEAT) && extras.getBoolean(KEY_REPEAT);
}


    public void scheduleRepeatingAlarm(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putBoolean(KEY_REPEAT, true);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                REPEAT_ALARM_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Calendar futureDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        futureDate.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) (INTERVAL_SEVEN_SECONDS / 1000));

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            setSingleExactAlarm(futureDate.getTime().getTime(), pIntent);
        } else {
            mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, futureDate
                    .getTime().getTime(), INTERVAL_SEVEN_SECONDS, pIntent);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To schedule a repeating alarm in `SDK versions >= 19`, when alarm broadcast is received , the boolean value `KEY_REPEAT` is checked and if it is true then a single exact alarm is scheduled for `INTERVAL_SEVEN_SECONDS / 1000` seconds later.
After `INTERVAL_SEVEN_SECONDS / 1000` seconds later the broadcast is again received and next alram is set.
This receiving broadcast and scheduling next alarm cycle repeats continuously.

Comment: Actually my error. I was confused about on recieved in my alarm manager class and in the notification class. Thanks very much